# Sandbox to Sandbox copy, Best Way

Tags: sandbox

We have an requirement where we to create copy our existing sandbox as new team would be using that soon.

We don't want to give them current production refresh copy (Which would have been easier, as it would just need to create copy from production).

I did some research and found that sales force don't allow copy one sandbox to another.

Another solution which we could find, is  that eclipse meta data migration from once sandbox to another.

Could you please help us in best approach.

Comment: You could use ANT migration tool too. It is quite efficient, reusable ..

Comment: Thanks Stygon. Could you please guide us as how by Using ANT Migration tool can we able to create full copy of current sandbox.

Comment: You could find the ANT guide in here - https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_migration_guide.pdf.

Comment: Additional blog links - http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/salesforce-migration-tool-ant/

http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/migration-using-ant-in-salesforce/

Comment: ANT can be used to migrate metadata NOT DATA, from one environment to another. It works based on the components you specify on your package.xml . First you will ned to retrieve the components from the source org( the components present on your package.xml) . Then you will have to deploy the components to your target org. Thus metadata will be migrated from one org to another. Dependency issues are bound to crop up like any other migration tool ex - deploying some code that references a field,object etc that hasn't been migrated to the target org will cause deployments to fail.

Comment: Thanks Stygon, You are awesome. Our plan is to copy 100 percent meta data to the org. Do you think our deployment still  fail as we are copying 100 percent meta data to org. I want be fully sure as i would recommend this to buisness. It would be nice if have any more points to add..Thanks

Comment: Since you planning to copy 100% of metadata less chance of dependency based failures I would say. May be am overlooking something. An useful information is - you could use the * wildcard to include all the components of a particular metadata type ex apex class, trigger, vf pages , objects etc.

Comment: So your package.xml would contain all the metadata types and * wildcard for the <members> tag. I am not sure if some metadata type does not support the * wildcard. Also please note that NOT ALL METADATA COMPONENTS are supported by the metadata api. So it is not possible to deploy these components as a part of migration. You would need to do manual steps . examples are duplication rules. Complete list - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm.

For any of the above components you have to manually create them in the target org.

Comment: Also please note that hardocoded parts of apex code, visualforce pages, custom buttons etc that contain org specific data also needs to be specifically updated to suit the target org. Hardocoded IDs are the chief culprits in this regard.

Comment: Thanks Stygon..You made my day..i will surely try this approach and let u know

Comment: Feeling is mutual pal. If it helped, post your venture please mark the question as solved as it will help anyone else visiting the question. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how urgent is your request. But checkout Summer 16 Release, and the new feature of Salesforce, [Sandbox-toSandbox cloning](https://blog.force365.com/2016/04/30/salesforce-summer-16-platform-highlights/?utm_content=buffer1a844&utm_medium=social&utm_source=linkedin.com&utm_campaign=buffer). You will be able to select from which org you want to create your sandbox from.

[image]

> **Sandbox-to-Sandbox Cloning**
>
> Recent releases have provided some
>   interesting enhancements in the sandbox area (post refresh scripts,
>   increased edition allowances etc.), Summer ’16 build on such
>   improvements with a new function that allows a sandbox to be created
>   as a clone of another sandbox (as opposed to a production org).
>   Superficially this sounds like a useful capability; on further thought
>   however this could have a significant impact on development process,
>   allowing QA sandboxes to be cloned as copies of development at the end
>   of sprint (as just one example). Any uni-lateral sandbox-to-sandbox
>   deployments could theoretically be replaced with a clone. Multiple
>   development sandboxes converging into a single upstream org would be
>   the exception. Cloning is also supported by the Tooling API, enabling
>   full automation of environment management. I’ve been unable test this
>   feature as sandbox copy doesn’t appear to be enabled in pre-release
>   orgs, however it would appear that data can be included in the clone.
>   How data copy works between the different sandbox types is yet to be
>   seen.

Comment: Thanks Brovasi. This is great news. But how can i check whether this feature has been available in our sales-force org or not. Has salesforce launched it already or this in pipeline.

Comment: It's not released yet, and they won't have any pre-release. Also how it will work exactly is to be confirmed But very exciting news. I was just thinking it would be good to mention it ;-) I would go for sure with ANT script as the other people proposed, it's free and quite easy, but might be a bit of works and some limitation with the API. There is also some good managed package on Appexchange if you are not a dev such as Copado, DreamFactory, Flosum.

Comment: ANT is the only way as August 31, 2016
Save Time by Cloning Sandboxes (Pilot)
Removed the release note for this feature, which won’t be available in the Summer ’16 timeframe. Need to wait!!

Comment: This is available as Beta Feature of Spring 18 release Click [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_sandbox_cloning.htm) for link

Answer (score 1):

ANT migration tool if a good alternative to eclipse migration. This involves migrating metadata using package.xml and components specified in it. It is highly efficient and reusable.

Answer (score 1):

David,
There are various products out there that can help with migrating metadata and data between sandboxes (and other Orgs). My own company, DreamFactory Software, makes a tool called SnapShot to migrate metadata and another called Monarch to migrate data (retaining relationships) between Orgs. Let me know if you want to see a demo and I am glad to give you a 15 min demo if you have the time.

Good luck!
Sridhar

Comment: Thanks Sridhar..Management is in process of getting licence of Dream Factory already..Till that in this release we have to do it another way. :)